# PWM on desired pin PIC18f47k40

Tags: pic, pwm, microchip, peripheral-pin-select

trying to question again.. Thanks in advance for any help!

I've been working with PIC chips for a while and recently using a PIC18f47k40. I cannot get the PWM via CCP or the separate PWM modules to work. I can flash the LED's on the pins by writing/clearing the LATx so I know the circuit is working correctly. I'm trying to get either CCP1 onto pin RC7 or PWM3 onto RD4. You'll see my trying to cycle their levels in main near the __delay_ms(1000) just trying to see something happen. The interrupt for Timer2 which both peripherals are set to.

```
/* 
 * File:   newmain.c
 * Author: lukebrenner
 *
 * Created on August 11, 2023, 8:17 AM
 */
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h> 



// PIC18F47K40 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode Selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINTOSC_64MHZ  // Power-up default value for COSC bits (EXTOSC operating per FEXTOSC bits (device manufacturing default))

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config MCLRE = EXTMCLR  // Master Clear Enable bit (If LVP = 0, MCLR pin is MCLR; If LVP = 1, RE3 pin function is MCLR )
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power up timer disabled)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config BORV = VBOR_2P45 // Brown Out Reset Voltage selection bits (Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config ZCD = OFF        // ZCD Disable bit (ZCD disabled. ZCD can be enabled by setting the ZCDSEN bit of ZCDCON)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF    // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly (subject to the unlock sequence))
#pragma config STVREN = OFF     // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger Enable bit (Background debugger disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Extended Instruction Set and Indexed Addressing Mode disabled)

// CONFIG3L
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31// WDT Period Select bits (Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // WDT operating mode (WDT enabled regardless of sleep)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7// WDT Window Select bits (window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required)
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC      // WDT input clock selector (Software Control)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 0 (Block 0 (000800-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT4 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT5 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT6 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT7 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG4H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-30000Bh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)
#pragma config SCANE = OFF      // Scanner Enable bit (Scanner module is NOT available for use, SCANMD bit is ignored)
#pragma config LVP = OFF       // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (HV on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming)

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP = OFF         // UserNVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (UserNVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // DataNVM Memory Code Protection bit (DataNVM code protection disabled)

// CONFIG5H

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 0 (Block 0 (000800-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR4 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR5 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR6 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 6 (Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR7 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#define _XTAL_FREQ 64000000 //changed from pic16f

//DIRECT DIGITAL SYNTHESIS <> DDS
volatile uint8_t index = 0;  
volatile uint32_t accu; //Accumulator 
volatile uint32_t ftw; //Frequency Tuning Word
volatile uint32_t localFTW;


    #define T0_SAMPLE_RATE      31250UL //  15625UL  
    #define ACCU_SIZE   4294967295UL


int main() {
    


    
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; //GLOBAL and >
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // > All PERIPHERAL interrups enabled
    INTCONbits.IPEN = 0; //Disables priority levels on interrupts
    
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////Timer2/CCP1 using PW3 for DDS////////////////////////////// Page 300 for list of associated registers
    RC7PPS = 0b00101; //0x05; // Temporarily changed to RC7 
    T2PR = 0b11111111; //0xff; //Period length, eh ?
    T2TMR = 0;

    T2CONbits.CKPS = 0b010; //prescaler  1:4
    T2CONbits.OUTPS = 0; //postscaler 1:1
    T2CONbits.ON = 1; //Timer2 On
    
    T2HLT = 0b10100000; // Prescaler sync to Fosc/4(slows down or better sync?), rising edge sync, ON-bit synced to timer clock ,Free running period
  
   
    
    CCP1CONbits.FMT = 1; //PWM mode left aligned
    CCP1CONbits.MODE = 0b1100; //PWM mode
    CCPTMRSbits.C1TSEL = 1; //CCP1 based on TMR2 
    
    CCPR1H = 0; //changed from CCPR1H/L ... is working better
    CCPR1L = 1;
    
    CCP1CONbits.EN = 1; //CCP Enabled
  
   
    PIR4bits.TMR2IF = 0; //Flag cleared
    PIE4bits.TMR2IE = 1; //Timer2 Interrupt when PR2 matched enabled  
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 0; //also changed to C7  //Wave output on B0
    ANSELCbits.ANSELC7 = 0;

   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   ///////////////PWM 3 for LED ////////////// /////////////////////////////// 
    

            
    RD4PPS = 0b00111; //0x07; //PWM3
    
    
    TRISDbits.TRISD4 = 0;
    ANSELDbits.ANSELD4 = 0;


    CCPTMRSbits.P3TSEL = 0b01; //PWM3 based on TMR2
    
    PWM3CONbits.EN = 1; //enables PWM3 should be done when LED turned on ?

 

    
    float currentRate = 120; //set to a general medium speed
    ftw = (uint32_t)(((currentRate+1) * (ACCU_SIZE / T0_SAMPLE_RATE)) / 10 ) + 0.5;
    
    TRISD4 = 0;
    ANSELD4 = 0; 
    TRISC7 = 0;
    ANSELC7 = 0;
    
    
  
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while(1){
        
        currentRate = 20;
        ftw = (uint32_t)(((currentRate+1) * (ACCU_SIZE / T0_SAMPLE_RATE)) / 10 ) + 0.5;
     
        TRISA3 = 1; 
        
        __delay_ms(1000);
        
        
        currentRate = 120;
        ftw = (uint32_t)(((currentRate+1) * (ACCU_SIZE / T0_SAMPLE_RATE)) / 10 ) + 0.5;
 
        TRISA3 = 0;
        
        __delay_ms(1000);
  
    }//end while
                    
   
}//end main


void interrupt ISR() {


    
  if(PIR4bits.TMR2IF == 1){//Timer2 triggers on overflow
      
  
     
        localFTW = ftw;
        accu += localFTW;
        index = (accu & 0xff000000) >> 24;
        CCPR1Hbits.RH = index; //being equal to index should create rising ramp
        PIR4bits.TMR2IF = 0; //resets flag
     
       
 
        
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this any different than your [previously deleted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/683027/51760)?

Comment: why did you post this again?

Comment: Its similar but i cleaned up the code a lot to make it manageable/ easier to work with... Stripped away everything except the CCP and PWM.

Comment: You are not supposed to do this, this site is not a forum. Instead, edit your original question. Make sure you **add** new information or source, to avoid making comments and answers useless.

Comment: Ah I saw the previous question was closed by a bot.. I didn't realize you could edit it, and resubmit...

Comment: Also the desired duty/frequency is that of an LFO, so below 20Hz... The currentRate variable being alternated should accomplish that

Comment: I wrote an answer to this a few days ago. Unclear if I should post here or there.

Comment: @Reinderien Here would be great with me

Comment: Sorry - I don't have access to my other build environment and won't again until November; but once I do I'll show you what was written. Long story short, there's a number of other registers that you should be setting explicitly, and you should be using symbolic masks to construct your register settings instead of bare hexadecimal values.

Comment: @Reinderien Thank you, will update the masks. Any suggestions on the other registers?

Comment: @Reinderien Updated the bit masks

Comment: I figured out my issues... I hadn't setup the Clock Selection Source for timer 2... needed to be Fosc/4 for both PWM to work

Answer (score 0):

OP has figured out the issue, but in the meantime I'll (finally) offer what I sketched up for this problem. A number of SFR settings were missing.

```c
#include <xc.h>

// PIC18F47K40 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode Selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINTOSC_64MHZ// Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with HFFRQ = 64 MHz and CDIV = 1:1)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled)
#pragma config CSWEN = OFF      // Clock Switch Enable bit (The NOSC and NDIV bits cannot be changed by user software)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config MCLRE = EXTMCLR  // Master Clear Enable bit (If LVP = 0, MCLR pin is MCLR; If LVP = 1, RE3 pin function is MCLR )
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power up timer disabled)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config BORV = VBOR_2P45 // Brown Out Reset Voltage selection bits (Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config ZCD = OFF        // ZCD Disable bit (ZCD disabled. ZCD can be enabled by setting the ZCDSEN bit of ZCDCON)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF    // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly (subject to the unlock sequence))
#pragma config STVREN = OFF     // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will not cause Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger Enable bit (Background debugger disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Extended Instruction Set and Indexed Addressing Mode disabled)

// CONFIG3L
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31// WDT Period Select bits (Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // WDT operating mode (WDT Disabled)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7// WDT Window Select bits (window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required)
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC      // WDT input clock selector (Software Control)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 0 (Block 0 (000800-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT4 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT5 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT6 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT7 = OFF       // Write Protection Block 3 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG4H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-30000Bh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)
#pragma config SCANE = OFF      // Scanner Enable bit (Scanner module is NOT available for use, SCANMD bit is ignored)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (HV on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming)

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP = OFF         // UserNVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (UserNVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // DataNVM Memory Code Protection bit (DataNVM code protection disabled)

// CONFIG5H

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 0 (Block 0 (000800-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR4 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR5 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR6 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 6 (Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR7 = OFF      // Table Read Protection Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)


void main(void) {
    /* Assumptions:
    PWM3 based on timer 2
    2-second period, 50% duty
    No interrupts
    Output to RC7 */
    
    // Explicitly enable PWM3, PWM4, CCP1, CCP2 (not all may be needed)
    PMD3 = 0;
    
    TRISC7 = 0;    // RC7 output
    ANSELC7 = 0;   // digital driver mode
    ODCC7 = 0;     // Push-pull
    
    // This can ONLY BE DONE on a 28-pin device (see 17.2)
    RC7PPS = 0x07; // PWM3 out to RC7
    
    // Configure timer 2 for slow period
    T2CLKCON = 0x4;  // LFINTOSC = 31 kHz
    T2HLT = (0 << _T2HLT_PSYNC_POSN)   // No fosc sync
          | (0 << _T2HLT_CKPOL_POSN)   // Input polarity doesn't matter
          | (0 << _T2HLT_CKSYNC_POSN)  // No input sync
          | (0 << _T2HLT_MODE_POSN);   // Freerun, period pulse, softgate
    
    /* (22.3) PWM for slow period
    Tosc = 31 kHz
    period ~ 2 s
    period = (T2PR + 1)4Tosc(TMR2 prescale)
    If T2PR < 255, prescale > 60.5 -> 128
    T2PR ~ 120, period ~ 1.998 s */
    T2PR = 120;
    T2CON = _T2CON_ON_MASK  // timer 2 enabled
          | (0x7 << _T2CON_CKPS_POSN)    // 1:16 prescale
          | (0x0 << _T2CON_OUTPS_POSN);  // 1:1 postscale, not used
    
    /* (22.4) PWM duty: assume 50%
    0.5 = PWM3DC(HL) / 4 / (T2PR + 1)
    PWM3DC(HL) = 242
               = 60<<2 | 2 (value starting from DCL MSB) */
    PWM3DC = ((uint16_t)242) << _PWM3DCL_PWM3DC0_POSN;
    PWM3CON = _PWM3CON_EN_MASK  // Enable
            // OUT is read-only
            | (0 << _PWM3CON_PWM3POL_POSN);  // Normal polarity
    
    // Shut off CPU and program flash memory; keep PWM running
    IDLEN = 1;
    for (;;) {
        asm("sleep");
    }
}
```